# create cart and place order through REST api magento

Tags: rest, api, magento

Hi i need to made a api for the mobile app ,

> at this moment i have check the magento apis
>
> and cant find the rest api to create a cart and place order through
>   REST.
>
> where as in soap it is possible.

Can you please suggest and refer me some links if it is possible to place order through rest . or how can i use rest for full app integration.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I am also stuck at the same step, already implemented some REST APIs, but i am not able to find REST APIS for Cart. They are there in SOAP.

Comment: No i didnot get yet.